# if-else in FreeMarker template

Tags: java, template-engine, freemarker

FreeMarker templates support an if-statement with the following syntax

```
<#if hot> 
  It's hot.
</#if>
```

I've looked in the documentation and can't find any support for an if-else statement. Of course, I could achieve the same result with:

```
<#if hot> 
  It's hot.
</#if>  
<#if !hot> 
  It's not hot.
</#if>
```

Is there support for if-else in FreeMarker?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, you can write:

```
<#if hot>
it's hot
<#else>
it's not
</#if>
```

And if you're doing lots of freemarker, I really can recommend IntelliJ IDEA 8, its freemarker support really helps...

Answer (score 19):

Yes, the sintaxis is:

```
<#if condition>
...
<#elseif condition2>
...
<#elseif condition3>
...
<#else>
...
<#/if>
```

You can find [Freemarker complete reference](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/)

If you are using Netbeans, there is [this plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginListPage.jsp?search=freemarker)

Comment: Thanks. Works with this syntax too [#if myVar?has_content && myVar==<someValue>]
...
[#elseif myVar?has_content && myVar==<someValue>]
...
[#else]
...
[/#if]

Answer (score 0):

*iberck* had already pointed out the docs. But here is the exact documentation about [if-else in FreeMarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_directive_if.html).

Comment: Go to the document iberk pointed out, search for if on that page and you get to: http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_directive_if.html